# Duplicate classes issue - while integrating native SDKs built using flutter in a flutter parent project

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, native-android

I have created native android and iOS SDK using flutter and now I need to integrate these SDKs in a parent flutter project. While integrating this way there are lot of duplicate files due to which the integration is not possible. The same set of files the parent project is trying to add as the native sdk built out of flutter. I cannot directly integrate sdk as flutter plugin. Anyway possible to integrate the existing native SDKs to flutter project?

I tried excluding few module and group in build.gradle but I cannot exclude all because those contains the SDK files.